# Is the JSON flair method going away soon on Area51?

Tags: support, area-51, flair

I noticed on the "Get Flair" page on Meta that:

> The earlier methods of sharing flair are deprecated and will go away eventually. Please use the simpler image flair from this point onward!

Will this be done for Area51 as well? The reason I'm asking is that I want to make sure you're **not** going to do it.

Why?

Well, the only way to get a user's reputation on Area51 is to call the JSON flair method. Area51 has no API. One of my apps uses this to retrieve a user's global reputation.

Comment: On that page, there's also a combined image flair, so possibly something else may be exposed in the API to get the summary information.

Comment: @Jon: http://stackapps.com/questions/1234/why-i-think-area51-needs-an-api